# Automatic folder creation when creating a new site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, document-library, site

Here is what I'm looking for.

When a new site is created I'd like four document libraries created automatically or I'd like to create a template that would have them already added.

I've read that saving a site as a template has been removed in 2013 and that is how we accomplished this in the past.

What (if any) are my options for accomplishing this?

Comment: Where have you read that Save site as template has been removed? That information is incorrect.

Comment: On another forum after not being able to locate the "save as template" link under site settings. Even with publishing features disabled I'm still not seeing it.

Comment: Clearly visible in all of my environments (without publishing enabled)

Answer (score 1):

First, create a Feature that provisions the libraries with the desired name/url/content types. Make that Feature hidden.

Second, create a web template and include the Feature as part of its configuration.

For specifics, I recommend the Tuesday sessions at http://spkbase.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Saving a site as a template isn't supported when Publishing is turned on so the link is removed if that feature is active.

/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx">You can still save a site as template using the below URL

Comment: With a high risk of it clashing when you try to use the template though. There is a good reason behind why MS has disabled this functionality for publishing sites